# Error in if (swagger) { :argument is not interpretable as logical

Tags: r, swagger, plumber

I am new using plumber, and I'm using the [Democratizing R with Plumber APIs - James Blair conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znHEW5Q6plw) material.  I am using the following material available on github [Cars Model API](https://github.com/sol-eng/plumber-model/tree/master/R/model-api), but running the entrypoint.R script, I get the following error. How can I fix it, I appreciate any help.

it works perfectly

```
library(plumber)

pr <- plumb(file = "plumber.R")
pr$run(port = 5762)
```

It doesn't work.

```
library(plumber)

pr <- plumb(file = "plumber.R")

pr$run(port = 5762,
      swagger = function(pr, spec, ...){
        # Define request body for POST to /predict
        spec$paths$`/predict`$post$requestBody <- list(
          description = "New data to predict",
          required = TRUE,
          content = list(
            `application/json` = list(
              # Define JSON schema
              schema = list(
                title = "Car",
                required = c("cyl", "hp"),
                properties = list(
                  cyl = list(type = "integer"),
                  hp  = list(type = "integer")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
        spec
      })
```

Error output

```
Starting server to listen on port 5762
Error in if (swagger) { :argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Comment: What version of `plumber` are you running?

Comment: My `pumber` version is `packageVersion("plumber") [1] ‘0.4.6’` and my R version is 4.0.2

Comment: It looks like your code requires the latest version which is not yet on CRAN. You can install the dev version with `remotes::install_github("rstudio/plumber")`

Comment: Really thank you very much was what I was looking for, it works.